# My PHP code is commented out

Tags: php, xampp

Before everything happened, I was running this wordpress install for developing themes using xampp. But I decided to upgrade the memory of this machine from 2GB to 6GB since I need extra room for applications. I back-up my code in a separate partition by copying them. Since I have a 32bit OS at the time, I format the computer and installed a 64bit version. All is well and fine the OS side.

When I setup my web dev environment something goes wrong.

When I imported my htdocs back, first by just fully copying them to a new fresh install of xampp and notice that all of the codes that put are not working. My CI code is displaying my PHP code in the browser. My theme in wordpress is also commenting out my PHP code when I view the source. The themes included in my fresh wordpress install works so there's something I am missing here.

[image: My Wordpress Theme when I activated it]

[image: My CodeIgniter Application when I browse it]

From the looks of it, the php is being executed properly since anything that I install works. Just that the ones that came from a previous xampp is not.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the short tags in php.ini? From the first glance it looks like that could be a problem.

Comment: Open up the `php.ini` file and set `short_open_tag=On`. Then restart apache and check if it worked.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: @smottt Thanks. It now works. Say, when I installed XAMPP this was left on by default. Why is it left out in the latest release?

Comment: Perhaps because the use of short tags is discouraged: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Might also be because the value changed in the bundled php.ini files from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3 from On to Off.

Comment: @MrA There is no need to edit the title and add "SOLVED". We know your issue is solved since you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up the `php.ini` file and set `short_open_tag = On`. Then restart apache.

Comment: better yet, change `<?` to `<?php` to ensure there aren't any problems when moving your code to a server where you have no control over, with `short_open_tag = Off` ;)

Comment: Totally agree on that. However since he is running some old wordpress installations I don't think he will be willing to replace all of `<?` to `<?php` in that codebase. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening a local script directly in the web browser, maybe through your editor, double-clicking on the file or dragging and dropping the file ito the browser - it will be treated as HTML only.

Instead, open the file by typing... `http://localhost/your-file.php` into the address bar. I personally create a projects folder in the htdocs folder and then create a bookmark for... `http://localhost/projects/`  and this will display all my projects that are saved into my projects folder.

Note: if you changed the mail port for the Apache server, you will need to add that to the path as well. eg. If your main port is 8888, your would do this... `http://localhost:8080/your-file.php`

I had the same problem and this worked for me. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the file was named as ".html". You must have an extension ".php"